# Difference between Select and More Like This(MLT) search

Tags: solr

My application is working fine with normal search (`/select?q=`) using SOLR.

Normal Query URL:
`/select?q=title:lovely`

Now want to implement More Like This (MLT) in my application. Configured MLT in Solr below like this.

### **solrconfig.xml**

```
  <requestHandler name="/mlt" class="solr.MoreLikeThisHandler">
  <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="mlt.fl">title</str>
            <str name="mlt.mintf">1</str>
            <str name="mlt.mindf">2</str>
            <str name="mlt.boost">true</str> 
  </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

**URL**:

`/mlt?q=title:lovely&mlt.fl=title`

I'm getting results and count with MLT same like normal select query. Can you please guide me if i did any wrong configurations for MLT?

Thanks in Advance,

AnilJayanti

Answer (score 2):

The settings in solrconfig.xml look correct to me.  As Paige Cook mentions in his answer, you'll get much better results if the fields you're using are set to store term vectors, `termVectors=true` in your schema.xml.  Term vectors can't be added after the fact, so you'll have to rebuild your index to add them in.  You might consider adding the `mlt.count` parameter to your request to get only the top N results.

My experience in getting good MLT results is that the parameters require some fine-tuning based on experimentation, in particular `mlt.mintf`. Start low and slowly increase until you start getting results that "feel right".  Similarity is a very subjective thing to try to quantify and will require some experimentation to get the right settings.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MoreLikeThis](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThis) documentation on the Solr Wiki, you need to either have TermVectors enabled for your field in your schema or the field must be stored.

Also, you might want to consider using the MoreLikeThisComponent in the SearchHandler as outlined in the link above. But that will be based on how you are planning to use/implement the MLT functionality in your application.